# How do you feel?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, poetry

> Someone's spilled coffee
>   On your white shirt.
>
> The report you spent
>   Four hours on,
>   Ruined in the rain.
>
> And someone's decided
>   That it'd be funny if you found,
>   Dragon dung in your in-tray.
>
> Just refactor,
>   A part of your life.
>
> And answer me this:

How do you feel right now? (Note: This is essentially a who-am-I riddle, only you get an extra hint: you're looking for a feeling...)

---

## Hint 1 -- *Helpfulness Level: $\frac{64}{100}$*

> Consider just the penultimate stanza ("just refactor...").

Comment: This reminded me of [raaaaiiin, on your wedding day...](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/alanismorissette/ironic.html)

Comment: @El-Guest - Very true!

Comment: I'd be hell of **frustrated**, to be honest

Comment: @BellaSwan - Also very true...

Comment: Feelings... Are you looking for emotion or tactile senses?

Comment: @CStafford-14 - It should be rather obvious given the content of the poem... This would be an emotion.

Comment: Does "Dragon dung" have any association with Harry Potter GoF?

Comment: @Jaystar - I just added that in as a little "Easter Egg" but the fact that it's Harry Potter has nothing to do with the puzzle or solution.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest puzzles have the most elusive solutions.... or maybe I just suck at puzzles.

Comment: @Cubemaster - I'm sure you're not _that_ bad. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be

> ireful

Explanation:

> Ireful means angry, so when the events happen, I would be angry of frustrated at something or someone. Rearranging or refactoring the phrase "your life"

Comment: Congratulations, first of all, on joining Puzzling SE! Second of all, that's exactly right and you earn 75 reputation for it! :D

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE!  Nice answer

Answer (score 3):

I feel

> foul

Explanation:

> If I take the "o" and "u" from "your" and the "l" and "f" from "life" I can rearrange (or refactor) them to get foul, which matches about how I'd feel after each of the aforementioned scenarios.

Comment: Good one! +1 Not exactly, though...

Answer (score 1):

the answer is:

> Indignation

explanation:

> This is the feeling of being treated unfairly, when odds are against you but you have no choice to change them.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:wordplay]?

Comment: Don't just take the poem's exact words, use parts of it (wordplay) to find a solution...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but is it

> pity

or

> failure

because both are kind of feelings that one feels when those things happen and can be formed by refactoring A part of your life.