# Some complicated clues

Tags: word

I am mud that will trap you. I am a colloid hydrogel. What am I?

Take the first half of me and add me to this:

I am dangerous to wolves and werewolves alike. Some people even say that I am dangerous to unholy things. Use the creator of Poirot to find out: What am I?

Now, take another word for your current result and only take the first four letters of it...

To fill in the rest of the letters, answer me this:

I am a fighter of luck, or something like that. What am I?

Take my last three letters, and to find out which letter to add to the beginning, answer me this:

I am trapped in the middle, and dead unlucky. What am I?

Finally, replace the last letter of what you have with this:

I am everywhere, what am I? <sup><sub><sup><sub>5</sub></sup></sub></sup>

---

**What are you left with?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am mud that will trap you. I am a colloid hydrogel. What am I?

> @Mohirl found it was Quicksand

Take the first half of me and add me to this:

> First half is Quick

I am dangerous to wolves and werewolves alike. Some people even say that I am dangerous to unholy things. Use the creator of Poirot to find out: What am I?

> This is Silver

Now, take another word for your current result and only take the first four letters of it...

> Quicksilver is also known as Mercury, so MERC-

To fill in the rest of the letters, answer me this:
I am a fighter of luck, or something like that. What am I?

> A fighter of luck may be a MERCENARY

Take my last three letters, and to find out which letter to add to the beginning, answer me this:

> So we have -ARY

I am trapped in the middle, and dead unlucky. What am I?

> The middle of the alphabet is either M or N, and dead unlucky clues the 13th letter, M. This leaves us with MARY.

Finally, replace the last letter of what you have with this:
I am everywhere, what am I?

> Potentially E, as the most common letter of the alphabet

What are you left with?

> MARE

Comment: Oooooohhh - You're so close that you can taste it! +1 Not entirely there yet, though...

Comment: @INTERESTING which steps are incorrect, if I might ask? I’m not sure starting at the fighter of luck step.

Comment: Umm... You messed up a little bit past halfway through! (The last four spoilers are incorrect...)

Comment: Last four or last five, @INTERESTING ?

Comment: Sorry I meant last three.

Comment: @INTERESTING I think I got the next spoilers, but I’m still not sure about the last one. Am I on the right track or should I be looking for something longer/in a different direction?

Comment: Cool! Updated my answer — feel free to delete your comment with the correct answer in it if you’d like others to solve, @INTERESTING. Great puzzle!!

Comment: Thanks bunches! I appreciate you trying your best to solve it! :D For more cool puzzles, check out [Hiker's Cabin Mystery | Pt. X](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86372/hikers-cabin-mystery-pt-x) or [How do you feel?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86427/how-do-you-feel). Both are puzzles by me which are still unsolved. Also, the first one has an open bounty of ***100 reputation***! Better get started!

Answer (score 2):

**Partial in progress**

I am mud that will trap you. I am a colloid hydrogel. What am I?

> Quicksand

Take the first half of me and add me to this:

> So quick + the next answer

I am dangerous to wolves and werewolves alike. Some people even say that I am dangerous to unholy things. Use the creator of Poirot to find out: What am I?

> Agatha Christie? AC? (Silver) bullet? Answer forms a compound word after 'quick'

Now, take another word for your current result and only take the first four letters of it...

To fill in the rest of the letters, answer me this:

I am a fighter of luck, or something like that. What am I?

Take my last three letters, and to find out which letter to add to the beginning, answer me this:

I am trapped in the middle, and dead unlucky. What am I?

Finally, replace the last letter of what you have with this:

I am everywhere, what am I? 5

Comment: rot13(Ntngun Puevfgv... Nt vf Fvyire)

Comment: Cheers, I'm assume that's what the intended answer is, but it's a bit of a stretch for me

Comment: @SteveV is correct...